# Find continuous (one after another) duplicated blocks of text and number the repetitions

Tags: python

I have a text where there are repeated blocks of texts(multiple lines) of different sizes.

Example:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
alpha game beta teta
Anvil Bravil Bruma
alpha game beta teta
Anvil Bravil Bruma
alpha game beta teta
Anvil Bravil Bruma
generator
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,
Lorem Ipsum  
is simply dummy text  
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,
Lorem Ipsum
is simply dummy text
```

Instead of having repeated blocks, I want to change to something like:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text == @3 times
==== repeated 3 times ==== 
alpha game beta teta
Anvil Bravil Bruma
generator  == @1 time
======== repeated 2 times ===
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text  
is simply dummy text
===============
```

The one line block, has a little different marking, because one line block can be repeated inside another block, recursive.

```
Lorem Ipsum 
Lorem Ipsum
hamdal
Lorem Ipsum 
Lorem Ipsum
hamdal
```

becomes

```
==== repeated 2 times ====
 Lorem Ipsum == @2 times
 hamdal
===========
```

When the same line is repeated multiple times, is easy to do (compare to the previous one - in memory),
but is hard to find a solution when the repeated block is formed of multiple lines and the number of lines variate.

I'm thinking on something that do some type of backtracking with a max limit for the number of lines that a block to check can have, but I didn't have a proper logic solution, so I'm looking for idea, some starting code.

Comment: Continuing from my previous point though, what if there are repeated blocks in repeated blocks? Should the output only include the largest block, or should it be recursive?

Comment: if is fully recursive block in block will be hard to read, so I was thinking recursive only for one line blocks, this is why one line blocks had @number at the end (different numbering/separator)

Comment: @wjandrea  thanks for the observations, I made some updates to reflect better what I need.

Comment: Before starting on duplicate blocks, you could do a first pass to detect duplicate lines. That's easy, like you said.

Comment: How would you process a  block fo 3 repeated lines for which the last two are part of a larger repeating block: ?  e.g.   `L1 ; L1 ; L1 ; L2 ; L1 ; L1 ; L2`.  Would that be `L1==@3times ; L2 ; L1 ==@2times; L2` or `L1; ===rep 2 times==; L1==@2times ; L2; =====` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set a maximum block size to look ahead for repetitions. It could be up to half the total number of lines but the larger it is the less efficient the process will be.

Advance in the lines by the largest possible repeating block from the current line.  Recurse for multi-line blocks.

From your expected output I gather that a single non-repeating line following a multi-line block must indicate "== @ 1 times" in order to delimit the end of the previous block.

```
def compact(lines,maxBlock=8):
    compacted = []                   # resulting lines
    def addBlock(start,size,count):  # add a block
        if size == 1:                # single line
            compacted.append(lines[start])
            if count:                # zero count == no repeat
                compacted[-1] += f"== @{count} times" # flag repeats
        else: # multi-line
            compacted.append(f"======== repeated {count} times ===")
            compacted.extend(compact(lines[start:start+size])) # recurse
    i = 0
    force1 = False      # force "@1 times" after end of multi-line block
    while i<len(lines):
        size = next(s for s in range(maxBlock,-1,-1) 
                    if lines[i:i+s]==lines[i+s:i+2*s])
        if not size:
            addBlock(i,1,1*force1) # No-repeat (except to signal end of block) 
            force1 = False         
            i += 1
            continue
        count = next( (j-i)//size for j in range(i,len(lines)+size,size)
                      if lines[i:i+size] != lines[j:j+size])
        addBlock(i,size,count)
        i += size*count
        force1 = size>1 # will force "@ 1 times" if next is single line
    return compacted
```

output:

```
lines = """Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
alpha game beta teta
Anvil Bravil Bruma
alpha game beta teta
Anvil Bravil Bruma
alpha game beta teta
Anvil Bravil Bruma
generator
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,
Lorem Ipsum
is simply dummy text
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,
Lorem Ipsum
is simply dummy text""".split("\n")

for line in compact(lines):print(line)

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text == @3 times
======== repeated 3 times ===
alpha game beta teta
Anvil Bravil Bruma
generator== @1 times
======== repeated 2 times ===
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,
Lorem Ipsum
is simply dummy text
```

...

```
lines = """Lorem Ipsum 
Lorem Ipsum
hamdal
Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum
hamdal""".split("\n")

for line in compact(lines):print(line)

======== repeated 2 times ===
Lorem Ipsum== @2 times
hamdal
```

*Note, it may be a good idea to strip trailing spaces from the lines before calling the function so that invisible differences don't prevent groupings*

Unless the notation was imposed, it may be easier to understand the compacted lines if the `addBlock` function indicated the number of lines that are repeated.  This way you wouldn't need the "@ 1 times" exception

```
def compact(lines,maxBlock=8):
    compacted = []                   # resulting lines
    def addBlock(start,size,count):  # add a block
        if size == 1:                # single line
            compacted.append(lines[start])
            if count: compacted[-1] += f" == @{count} times" # flag repeats
        else:
            block = compact(lines[start:start+size])
            compacted.append(f"=== next {len(block)} lines repeated {count} times ===")
            compacted.extend(block) # recurse
    i = 0
    while i<len(lines):
        size = next(s for s in range(maxBlock,-1,-1) if lines[i:i+s]==lines[i+s:i+2*s])
        if not size:
            addBlock(i,1,0) # No-repeat (except to signal end of block) 
            i += 1
            continue
        count = next( (j-i)//size for j in range(i,len(lines)+size,size)
                      if lines[i:i+size] != lines[j:j+size])
        addBlock(i,size,count)
        i += size*count
    return compacted
```

Alternate outputs:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text  == @3 times
=== next 2 lines repeated 3 times ===
alpha game beta teta
Anvil Bravil Bruma
generator
=== next 3 lines repeated 2 times ===
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,
Lorem Ipsum
is simply dummy text
```

...

```
=== next 2 lines repeated 2 times ===
Lorem Ipsum == @2 times
hamdal
```

*You could do something similar for the single line repetitions showing `=== next line repeated 3 times ===` before the line (for example)*